# UIScrollView: Pickup Scroll Mid-Swipe

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

I'm attempting to add a scrollview to the view and have its scroll initiated as soon as it hits with the finger already down on the screen. As of now I am clicking a button that makes the scrollview appear on top of it... this means I click, then have to lift my finger, then place it back down to begin scrolling.

Is there anyway to have the scrollview start scrolling even though the touch down has already occurred? Or to pass that touch saved from the button to the scrollview as soon as it appears so that it will drag? Or possibly fake the start of the touch altogether once the scrollview starts?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but could you use touchesMoved? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesMoved:withEvent:

Comment: Josiah, thanks for the suggestion. I tried touches moved but the problem is actually a bit more complicated. When the button is pressed its not just that a scrollview is added... its that an entire new view is added modally on top that contains the scrollview... thus any touches on the first view are cancelled. I need a way to save them before they are cancelled and pass them to the modally presented view that instantly appears on top. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have my computer today. (Going Chromebook style), however I believe you can actually use touchesMoved, and pass the NSSet *touches, to to your other view, then do `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event; `yourself. You'd have to try some things to find a way to do this properly.

Comment: Josiah, thanks so much! I'll go ahead and give it a go and let you know the results!

Comment: Zach, Alright. Good luck!